Tauri state not managed even if manage is called
I have a very basic Tauri app, where I try to manage state. My app compiles, but if I invoke a command from the frontend I got the following runtime error: state is not managed for field state on command test_cmd. You must call .manage() before using this command
I build my Tauri app the way below. As you can see there is the .manage() call
#[cfg_attr(mobile, tauri::mobile_entry_point)]
pub fn run() {
    let db_state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(DatabaseState::new()));

    println!("db_state initialized ");

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
            app.get_webview_window("main").unwrap().open_devtools();
            Ok(())
        })
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
        .manage(db_state)
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![test_cmd])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

And my command looks like this (This is a simplified command just for demonstrating the error):
#[tauri::command]
pub async fn test_cmd(state: State<'_, Arc<Mutex<DatabaseState>>>) -> Result<String, String> {
    Ok("test_cmd executed".into())
}

And my DatabasState is the following:
pub struct DatabaseState {
    service: Option<BoxedDatabaseService>,
}

impl DatabaseState {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DatabaseState { service: None }
    }

    pub fn set_service(&mut self, db_service: BoxedDatabaseService) {
        self.service = Some(db_service);
    }

    pub fn get_service(&self) -> Option<&BoxedDatabaseService> {
        self.service.as_ref()
    }

}

Any commands that don't use state works just fine.
Any idea how to solve this issue or what I should check?

Try calling app.manage in the setup code instead of on the Builder

Does Mutex mean the same thing in both places?

Check full types. One Mutex may be from tokio and the other maybe from std or something like that

Thanks to @kmdreko and @Timsib Adnap I found the problem. I didn't recognize the different types. It was really mixed. One time from tokio and one time from std.
